# Launch my android application from android browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I have used below code to launch application from Opera mini in Android device. It is not loading application every time. If i am changing URI every time, then it will work every time but if i used same URI then it will launch once but not loading application next attempts.

Code:

```
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="nvin.scan"  />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

And i have also checked for Youtube for same. if i have used URI for Youtube(i.e vdn.youtube://) in browser then it will work for every time. so please let me know what i need to change in my code to work same like for Youtube.

Thanks,

Comment: For technical support with Opera mini, you are best served by asking Opera. If things behave correctly in other browsers -- and, off the cuff, I would expect them to -- then this is an Opera-specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply 
I have read similar thread for it and its said that this will be work in Opera mini and Chrome browser of Android device and I have checked it in default browser for Youtube link and its not working and its working in opera mini every time. but for my application is not working for every time as i mentioned above.

Comment: I have checked this in Android OS 4.0 and its working fine in it but having issues which i have mentioned above in Android 2.2 to 2.3.6.

Comment: Try this decision
[Launch custom android application from android browser][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser